# Analysis Services Deployment Wizard Error: Database already exists

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, tabular

I have a Tabular cube on my SSAS server. I have made many partitions and have processed data for last couple of months.

I want make minor changes to my project and deploy again. If I deploy from Visual Studio, I will loose my partitions on server, ever I choose `"Do not Process"` in project option.

I searched but did not find any proper way to do this.

I thought I should import the database in Visual Studio and make my changes and deploy. Is this a good way to do? Is there any other way than this?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Deploy' process erases all data in the cube, including dimensions and partitions. The 'Do not process' option does only what it says: it does not process the cube.
Depending on the changes, you can choose the 'Deploy changes only' option in project-> properties-> deployment-> deployment mode. But it depends on how 'minor' the changes are.

Comment: I don't see the "Deployment Mode" !! I check VS 2010 and 2013

Comment: Try using Deployment Wizard from SQL Server: First, build solution in VS. That creates .asdatabase file in bin folder (on your project folder). Then, run Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server -> Analysis Services -> Deployment Wizard. This is more controllable option. Follow instructions, configure how partitions and role should be deployed.